# Making a function that calculate a staggered function in power bi

Tags: r, powerbi, dax, kpi

I come to you with the following challenge. I need to do a KPI on Power BI related to maintenance sector -calculate the Availability of certain machine -. The formula to calculate is the following one:

```
Availability (fip, ftp) = Working time in period fip-ftp /Total Operating Time, where:
fip = initial date of evaluation, ftp = final date of evaluation.

Working Time = Total Operating Time in period fip - ftp - Downtime in period fip - ftp.
Total Operatinal Time = Working Time of Machine in a day * (ftp-fip)
(ftp-fip) = delta time of evaluation
```

As you can see i need to see the Availability between fip  and ftp, be available to "play" with this date (it will be great to do using a slider in Power Bi, and the KPI changes depending the dates).

Soo, in order to do this i have the date in this format:

[image: Table]

For example, if i want to get the KPI for Machine A and B for:`fip = 01/07/2019 and ftp=20/12/2019` you will notice that fip date selected happens before Detention Date and ftp is before Start Date, soo the Availability for each maquine it will be:

[image: Table2]

As you notice you will have multiple cases, but the case asume that if a machine has a failure it can´t operate until is fixed. The cases that i need to program are the following:

A) Detention Date `<`fip and Start Date `<`fip, that a means that the time down is 0.

B) Detention Date `<`fip and Start Date `>`fip, that a means that the time down is `Start Date - fip`.

C) Detention Date `>`fip and Start Date `<`ftp, that a means that the time down is `Start Date - Detentión Date`.

D) Detention Date `>`fip and Start Date `>`ftp, that a means that the time down is `Start Date - ftp`.

I need to program in power bi with the idea of using a slicer so the user can see de Availability on any period of time. Any help is gratefully appreciated.